# How to launch couple of .sh in one command?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have some files in a folder and want to launch them in one command. Structure looks like this:

```
keddad@keddad-HP:/media/$ ls
somfile.sh
otherfile.sh
onemorefile.sh
```

So I'm trying to do it with a command:

```
./*
```

But it starts only first file, ignoring others in the folder. How can I launch them all in one time (or make them to work one-by-one, so the second will start after terminating the first one)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you tried ./* , the shell saw the single command:

```
./somfile.sh ./otherfile.sh ./onemorefile.sh
```

Or, in other words, it saw one command (./somefile.sh) with two arguments (./otherfile.sh ./onemorefile.sh)

To run them one-by-one (sequentially):

```
for each in ./* ; do "${each}" ; done
```

To run them all at once (simultaneously / parallel):

```
for each in ./* ; do "${each}" & done
```